# How to split a string on multiple regular expressions while keeping the splitting characters

Tags: regex, string, scala, split, lexer

I'm writing a lexer/scanner for the first time, and have run into a problem splitting the input-string.
Example:

```
val result = "func add(Num x, Num y) = x+y;".split(???) 
result == Array("func", "add", "(", "Num", "x", ",", "Num", "y", ")", "=", "x", "+", "y", ";")
```

But the problem is that I can't simply split on whitespace characters, doing so wouldn't separate `add` from `(` for example.

Any help with this?

Comment: Don't *speak* scala ;), so I can't tell you how to handle the empty entries, but splitting on `\s|\b` - adding word boundry - should do it. See [regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/lB7sB3/2)

Comment: @ClasG that did the trick, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a bunch of empty items that your EE will have to handle, but adding word boundry - `\b` - should do it.

Check [example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lB7sB3/2).

I.e. `...split('\s|\b')` (or `/\s|\b/`).

Regards

Comment: If I'm not wrong this will add spaces in the result which I think is not the expected

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

Here is an unfinished example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

trait Element

case class Function(name: String,
                    params:Map[String, String],
                    expression:Seq[String]) extends Element

case class Class(name: String,
                 params: Map[String,String],
                 body: Seq[String]) extends Element

object LanguageParser extends RegexParsers {

  val name: Parser[String] = ".*".r

  val `type`: Parser[String] = ???

  val parameters: Parser[Map[String,String]] = "(" ~> (`type` ~ name).* <~")" ^^ {
    case t => (t map {
      case a ~ b => a -> b
    }).toMap
  }

  val expression: Parser[Seq[String]] = ???

  val function: Parser[Function] =
    "func " ~> name ~ parameters ~ "="~ expression ^^ {
      case name ~  params ~ _ ~ expr => Function(name, params, expr)
    }
  
  val `class`: Parser[Class] =
    "class " ~> name ~ parameters ~ "{" ~ expression ~ "}" ^^ {
      case name ~  params ~ _ ~ expr ~_ => Class(name, params, expr)
    }

  val topLevelParsers: Parser[Seq[Element]] =
    function |
      `class` |
      value |
      ifelse

  def parse(s: String): Seq[Element] = parseAll(topLevelParsers, s.trim) getOrElse
    (throw newIllegalArgumentException("Could not parse the given string: " + s.trim))

  def parseAll(s: String):Seq[Element] =
    s split ";" flatMap parse
}
```

Cheers

Comment: For now the \b|\s is sufficient. but i fear i might have to rewrite the code i have, and learn about the regex parser to achieve a more reliable solution. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: You'll save time learning it straight away. I didn't the first time because I was lazy, I had to rewrite everything and keep saying why I didn't know about this before.